# Sending each element from an array into a separate CSV row

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script that puts each element of an array into it's own separate row in a .CSV. So far this is what the script looks like:

```
$table = @()

(gci *.xml -Recurse -force | select-string -pattern "RestrictedGroups" -List | select-xml -xpath *) | sort | foreach {
$gpo = $_.Path
[xml]$xml = gc $gpo 
$Name = $xml.GPO.Name
$GroupName = @($xml.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension.RestrictedGroups.GroupName.Name."#text")
$MemberOf = @($xml.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension.RestrictedGroups.MemberOf.Name."#text")

$Record = New-Object PSObject
$Record | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name"        -Value $Name
$Record | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "GroupName"      -Value $var2
$Record | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MemberOf"  -Value $var3

$table += $Record

}

$table | Export-CSV c:\temp\gpo.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ","
```

"Name" will always have a count of 1, the others frequently have higher counts. Sample output:

```
Name GroupName                  MemberOf
1    aaa                        System.Object[]
2    bbb                        ccc
3    System.Object[]            System.Object[]
```

As you can see, many of the values in the CSV are output as "System.Object[]" instead of the values I'm trying to extract. In some cases they show up as the actual name I'm looking for (aaa, bbb) and I suspect this is the case when there's only one element in the array.

Using set-content instead of export-csv has almost worked, except when I do that, each element of the array is put into a single cell. I can add a comma delimiter, but than that just adds the new elements into the next column cell over instead of the next row cell down.

Any ideas on how I can get it so that each element of the arrays for member and LocalGroup is put into it's own cell under their respective headers?

Here's a sample XML file that this will run against:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<GPO xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings">
  <Computer>
    <ExtensionData>
      <Extension xmlns:q1="xxx" xsi:type="q1:SecuritySettings">
        <q1:RestrictedGroups>
          <q1:GroupName>
            <SID xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">SID</SID>
            <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">MemberName</Name>
          </q1:GroupName>
          <q1:Memberof>
            <SID xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">SID2</SID>
            <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">MemberOf</Name>
          </q1:Memberof>
          </q1:RestrictedGroups>
         </Extension>
       </ExtensionData>
  </Computer>
```

Comment: J. Scott - your csv file has arrays of objects in those positions. [*grin*] you need to expand the array and either convert it to a string OR create a new property for each item in the collection. the 1st of those it the usual fix. something like `$Collection -join '; '` is one common way to fix the problem.

Comment: So do you want a row for every single member of for every single group name? In the above case would the name column be duplicated for 1 and 3?

Comment: OK, thanks Lee_Dailey. I'm getting parameter not found using -join. In this case I'd be putting that after my variables $GroupName and $MemberOf correct?

Comment: Matt that's right, that's the only way I can think of to do this although in practice I'm not exactly sure how that would work. I suppose it's possible I'd wind up just getting a normal column of "name" and then the output of the arrays extends beyond that.

Comment: I thought i had an answer, but the truth is, Excel just can't do multi tier spreadsheets. they are flat. So that's why json and xml exists.  but it depends on what you're expanding, if it's just lists of strings, and you want to expand everything belonging to it's owner, i mean i don't doubt there's a way, but i would look into json/xml for my answer at this level of difficulty...

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to solve this since yesterday as well. My quick and dirty solution so far is to use the `Add-Content` cmdlet to add the data to the Csv file directly. This adds all the info from the array into one cell block.

What this looks like for your code is:
`Add-Content -Path c:\temp\gpo.csv -Value "$name, $var2, $var3"`

Note: The commas are used as column delimiters for Csvs.